# Video with alpha for Processing

Tags: video, processing, augmented-reality, alpha

I am researching how to play alpha videos in processing to make augmented reality. What is the format and encoding needed to render video files with alpha channel?

When I do this in Unity I use a special shader and video format so can use luma cut, whereas in the same video you put the white and black in one side (or up) and the color in the other side (or down), then the shader makes "the magic" and leaves the color over to cutted image.

Here is a link to previous post: [Video with alpha channel in Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306260/video-with-alpha-channel-in-processing/36016254?noredirect=1#comment59684054_36016254)

Comment: adding code and posting stacktrace will help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video with alpha channel in Processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306260/video-with-alpha-channel-in-processing)

Comment: The question you linked already has an answer that explains exactly how to show a video with an alpha channel. What happened when you followed those directions?

Comment: yes, indeed I posted the same on that question. I think using luma in two separated videos will be the first solution that will try. Posting Unity code and shader don´t think will help´, here is the post where I explain and paste code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239136/vuforia-it-is-possible-play-a-movie-texture-with-alpha-in-ios/33659114#33659114

Comment: Is this question about Processing or about Unity? The linked answer contains Processing code. Why don't you try that and post a [mcve] if you get stuck?

Comment: @KevinWorkman that post shows how to do alpha blend of the videocapture with an overlay, it does not explain format and encoding of the video to render with aplha channel, nor how to successfully use videos with transparency on the borders of the image: for example only a person with transparent borders (no background image)

Comment: @KevinWorkman is for processing, I just posted how I solve it in unity :)

Comment: @user3084244 You're going to have to break your problem down into smaller individual questions. Start with the duplicate answer and get something basic working, then post a [mcve] if you get stuck.

Comment: solved, answer posted in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306260/video-with-alpha-channel-in-processing/36045584#36045584